# How to get all the js and css dependencies from a web page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-upload-file-plugin

I am using the [JQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugin and had issues using it from IE 9.x then I found out that this was a known issue and checked out again their example that works on IE 9.x no problems. However, in my project if I manually download dependency by dependency I  can't get it to work in IE 9.x exactly as in the online File Upload example. Therefore this question, how can I get all the css and js dependencies on that Web Page so I can reproduce the same working solution for IE 9.x. It is actually a very tricky business because changing js library version between related dependencies can lead to broken functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For browsers under IE9 capabilities you can try the following plugin :

https://github.com/LPology/Simple-Ajax-Uploader

It works IE7+ .. so it's wow.

Your code might look like this :

```
var uploader = new ss.SimpleUpload({
    button: $('.js-uploadBtn'), // upload button
    url: '/uploadhandler', // URL for server-side upload handler
    name: 'userfile', // name of the uploaded file
    onSubmit: function() {
        this.setProgressBar( $('.js-progressBar') ); // beautiful progress bar 
    },
    onComplete: function(file, response) {
        // after upload handler 
    }
});
```